# How do I assign another hard disk to root in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm

The following is the current status of my disk:

```
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0   62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop1                       7:1    0   62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1611
loop2                       7:2    0 79.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22923
loop3                       7:3    0  103M  1 loop /snap/lxd/23541
loop4                       7:4    0   47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
sda                         8:0    0   60G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0    2G  0 part /boot
├─sda3                      8:3    0   28G  0 part 
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   28G  0 lvm  /
├─sda4                      8:4    0   30G  0 part 
└─sda5                      8:5    0 1007K  0 part 
sr0                        11:0    1  1.4G  0 rom
```

I added sda4 as above, is there any way to increase the root capacity to sda4?

Comment: There are other forums with **mounting** a disk at some directory, typically /home.

Comment: joopEggen/ I want to mount root.

Comment: That is possible but look in a linux forum. When you want an other boot disk and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the VG and LV by commands:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda4
vgextend ubuntu--vg /dev/sda4
lvextend -L+4GB /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

The last command add 4 GB space to `/`
and then extend your filesystem. It it's `ext4` use command:

```
resize2fs /
```

If its `XFS` you can use command

```
xfs_growfs -d /
```

Both resize commands can be done on the fly (w/o unmount the filesystem)